# NLog for .Net Core is not logging Debug information

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, c#-3.0, nlog

I've recently started writing .Net Core applications and I'm using NLog for my logging. I came up with the following NLog.config file. This will log if I use `_log.LogInformation("Log an INFO");` but not if I use `_log.LogDebug("Log a DEBUG");`.

I do not have any logging settings in my appsettings.json file. I typically write console applications and VisualStudio template for console apps does not have any logging automatically added to appsettings.

I'm using .Net Core 3.1 with the following NLog package.

```
<PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.9.3" />
```

Anyone see why using the Debug wouldn't write to the log file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <variable name="LogDirectory" value="D:\logs\ProjectName"/>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    
    <target xsi:type="File" 
      name="DefaultTarget" 
      fileName="${LogDirectory}\LogFile.log"
      layout="${longdate} | ${callsite} | ${message}"
      archiveAboveSize="3145728"  
      archiveEvery="Day"
      archiveFileName = "${LogDirectory}/Archive/{#}.log"  
      archiveNumbering = "DateAndSequence"            
      archiveDateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"  
      maxArchiveFiles = "21"            
    />

    <target name="ConsoleTarget"
      xsi:type="Console"
      layout="${longdate} ${logger:shortName=True} ${message} ${onexception:EXCEPTION OCCURRED\:${exception:format=type,message,StackTrace,method:maxInnerExceptionLevel=8:innerFormat=type,message,StackTrace,method}}"
    />
    
  </targets>  
  <rules>
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" /> <!-- BlackHole without writeTo -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="DefaultTarget,ConsoleTarget" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Missing-trace%5Cdebug-logs-in-ASP.NET-Core-3%3F

Comment: Thanks....that looks like it might have worked. I didn't have any log settings of any kind in my appsettings.json file. I added the log settings from the link above to my appsettings and it looks like it worked. Making notes for next and adding them to my project template.

Comment: Hopefully with NLog 5.0 then it will no longer be required. Found a secret trick to remove this speciality: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/issues/483

Comment: As Rolf said, the issue is relates the [Log levels](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#log-levels), if the minimum level is Info, then Info, Warn, Error and Fatal are logged, but Debug and Trace are ignored. To configure the log levels, we could use the SetMinimumLevel method or the appsettings.json, more detail information, refer [this sample](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3).

Comment: None of this works for me. I have the Log levels as, {
          "logger": "*",
          "minLevel": "Debug",
          "writeTo": "logfile"
        } inside the NLog configuration section and the general logging config section as below:
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "System": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace",
        "System": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Debug"
      }
    },